# Get value from text input after focusout & display data from that value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-focusout

I have 3 input text for UserID, UserName, and email;

```
<input type="text" name="UserID" class="form-control" id="input-loader" placeholder="User ID">
<input type="text" name="UserName" class="form-control" id="user-show" placeholder="User Name">
<input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" id="email-show" placeholder="Email">
```

in My database:

UserID(string) | UserName(string) | email(string)

satriodwih | Satrio DwiHuripto | sdwihuripto@lala.com

1. textbox UserId is shown but textbox UserName and email is hidden
2. When I type satriodwih in userID and focusOut(click tab or click outside the textbox), textbox username and email shown and their value comes from database.

And I Have jquery for focusout like this :

```
$(function () {
$body = $("body"),
$("#user-show").hide(),
$("#email-show").hide(),
$(function () {
    $("#input-loader").focusout(function () {
        var UserIDc = document.getElementById("#input-loader");
        $(function () {
            $.get("/mockjax", function () {
                $("#user-show").show(),
                $("#email-show").show(),
            });
        });
    });
});
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); },
    ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
});});
```

What must I do? Stuck too long time.

Comment: Your not setting the values of the inputs `user-show` and `email-show` in your `$get() method. Add your controller action so we can see what is returned.

Comment: Why not use `blur` instead? What is actually wrong, what is not working?

Comment: Also you don't need `#` in getElementById. Either do: `var UserIDc = document.getElementById("input-loader");` (plain javascript) **or** `var UserIDc = $("#"input-loader");` (using jQuery Selector),

Comment: focusout is working. I can't get value of userID when I type it. The textbox have hide and shown when focusout from textbox. But it's null.

Comment: how to pass userIDc in my view? i want to use it for get information about username and email from that userIDc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a controller action method that returns json containing the UserName and Email like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetUserData(string userID)
{
    string userName = ...; // get user name from database here
    string email = ""; // get email from database here

    return Json(new { ID = userID, UserName = userName, Email = email }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then change your script section to this:

```
$(function () {
    $body = $("body");
    $("#user-show").hide();
    $("#email-show").hide();
    $(function () {
        $("#input-loader").focusout(function () {

            // get value from input-loader textbox
            var UserIDc = $(this).val();

            $(function () {
                // call /home/getuserdata and pass the user id from input-loader textbox
                $.get("/home/getuserdata?userID=" + UserIDc, function (result) {

                    // set user name and email textbox value 
                    $('#user-show').val(result.UserName);
                    $('#email-show').val(result.Email);

                    // show user name and email textbox
                    $("#user-show").show();
                    $("#email-show").show();
                });
            });
        });
    });
    $(document).on({
        ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); },
        ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
    });
});
```

Please note that I use the url `/home/getuserdata` in the above code because I assume the `GetUserData` action method is in `HomeController.cs`. If `GetUserData` is in a different controller then you must change the url, i.e `/users/getuserdata` if it's in `UsersController.cs`.

Comment: THANKYOU VERY MUCH. IT'S USEFUL. ({ }) Helps very much. That was I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Why you have a lot of functions in together?

The problem is using `#` in `document.getElementById("#input-loader");`. You should remove that.

```
$(function () {
    $body = $("body"),
    $("#user-show").hide(),
    $("#email-show").hide(),

    $("#input-loader").blur(function () {
        // you should not use # here:
        // var UserIDc = document.getElementById("input-loader"); 
        // and also it's simpler to use:
        var UserIDc = $("#input-loader");

        $.get("/mockjax", function () {
            $("#user-show").show(),
            $("#email-show").show(),
        });

    });

    $(document).on({
        ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); },
        ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
    });
});
```

Comment: how to use UserIDc in my view?

Comment: for example : I want to use UserIDc into : <input type="text" name="UserName" class="form-control" id="user-show" value="@Html.Display(UserIDc)">  How??

Comment: OK I got it. `UserIDc` is a client-side/javascript variable and it doesn't exist at server at all. If you want to pass it to the server you can post it via ajax request which is absolutely not usable in `@Html.Display(UserIDc)`. But if you want to display the `UserIDc` in `<input ... />`, you can use `$("#user-show").val(UserIDc);`